# Approximate $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{k}{m-k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

How do I approximate (or better find a closed formed formula) for $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{k}{m-k}$, where $m$ is large.

This looks suspiciously like a partial sum for the harmonic series, but I do know how to find a closed form for it. (Unless I missed something obvious).

Any help or insights is appreciated

Comment: I think one possible approach is to just the sun be $S$ and then subtract $S$ from $mH_m$

Comment: $\frac k{m-k}=\frac m{m-k}-1$...

Answer (score 6):

$ \textbf{Hint :} $ \begin{aligned}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}{\frac{k}{m-k}}&=\sum_{k=1}^{m}{\frac{m-k}{k}}\\ &=mH_{m}-m\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

The closed-form solution is $$\gamma  m-m+m \psi ^{(0)}(m)+1$$

using the Euler gamma and polygamma functions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have been given the exact result.

If you want a good *approximation*, using the asymptotics of harmonic numbers
$$mH_{m}-m\sim m (\log (m)+\gamma -1)+\frac{1}{2}-\frac 1 {12m} \Bigg[1-\frac{55671 m^2+110200}{105 \left(5302 m^4+13020 m^2+3549\right)} \Bigg]$$ which is $O\left(\frac{1}{m^{11}}\right)$.

For $m=10$, the approximation is in an absolute error of $4.82\times 10^{-14}$