# A sum similar to Harmonic numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, harmonic-numbers

Consider the sum $$S_n=\sum_{r=2}^n \frac{(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}}{r-1}          $$
My question is: What is the asymptotic for $S_n$ as $n\to \infty$ or find $R_n$ such that $S_n\sim R_n$ as $n\to \infty$.

My try:
Define the $n$th Harmonic number as $$H_n=\sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r}$$ Then we also have (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number ) $$H_n=\sum_{r=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{r-1} \binom{n}{r}   }{r} $$
Then we have the asymptotic equivalence of $H_n$ as $$H_n\sim \log n+\gamma +\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
How to find the asymptotic equivalence of $S_n$?

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341389/approximate-sum-limits-k-0m-1-frackm-k/4341546#4341546

Comment: @Claude Leibovici Thank you. But how is my $S_n$ related to the sum given in your link. In my sum we have an alternating sum whivh is not the case in the sum given in this link

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I saw that in the link given by you, you have provided an answer. It would be very helpful if you would write as a short answer for this question.

Comment: Using the binomial identity, you can write $S_n = \int_{0}^{1}\tfrac{(1-x)^n-1+nx}{x^2}\,dx$ and then get asymptotics for $S_n$ by bounding the integral. I'll write a full answer soon.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I really thank you for your insights. I will be reall happy to accept your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I don't understand how the link given by : Claude Leibovici answers my question. The sum in the link and the sum in my question are different. I am sorry if I am missing something trivial.

Comment: @Mary $S_n =nH_n-n$, see my answer below.

Comment: See more generally https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform , a fascinating field ranging e.g. from harmonic numbers ($\frac {1}{r}$) to Laguerre polynomials ($\frac {1}{r!}$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
S_n & = \sum\limits_{r = 2}^n {\frac{{( - 1)^r }}{{r - 1}}\binom{n}{r}}  = n\sum\limits_{r = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{{( - 1)^{r +1} }}{{r(r + 1)}}\binom{n-1}{r}} \\ & = n\sum\limits_{r = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{{( - 1)^{r + 1} }}{r}\binom{n-1}{r}}  + n\sum\limits_{r = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{{( - 1)^r }}{{r + 1}}\binom{n-1}{r}} 
\\ &
 = nH_{n - 1}  + n\int_0^1 {\left[ {(1 - x)^{n - 1}  - 1} \right]dx}  = nH_{n - 1}  - n\frac{{n - 1}}{n} \\ &= nH_n  - n.
\end{align*}
Thus, we have an exact expression for $S_n$ in terms of $H_n$. The asymptotic expansion follows from that of $H_n$, i.e.,
$$
S_n  \sim n\log n - (1 - \gamma )n + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{{12n}} + \frac{1}{{120n^3 }} -  \cdots 
$$
as $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for this beautiful answer.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with the binomial identity $$(1-x)^n = \sum_{r = 0}^{n}(-1)^r\dbinom{n}{r}x^r,$$ we can subtract $1-nx$ from both sides and divide both sides by $x^2$ to get $$\dfrac{(1-x)^n-1+nx}{x^2} = \sum_{r = 2}^{n}(-1)^r\dbinom{n}{r}x^{r-2}.$$ Integrating both sides from $0$ to $1$ yields $$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{(1-x)^n-1+nx}{x^2}\,dx = \sum_{r = 2}^{n}\dfrac{(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}}{r-1} = S_n.$$ So we can find asymptotic for $S_n$ using the above integral. We split the integral into two pieces. One over $[0,1/n]$ and one over $[1/n,1]$.

For the first piece, one can check that $f(x) := \tfrac{(1-x)^n-1+nx}{x^2}$ is decreasing on $[0,1/n]$, and so $$\dfrac{1}{n}f\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right) \le \int_{0}^{1/n}f(x)\,dx \le \dfrac{1}{n}f(0),$$ $$\dfrac{1}{n} \cdot n^2\left(1-\tfrac{1}{n}\right)^n \le \int_{0}^{1/n}\dfrac{(1-x)^n-1+nx}{x^2}\,dx \le \dfrac{1}{n} \cdot \dbinom{n}{2}$$ $$n\left(1-\tfrac{1}{n}\right)^n \le \int_{0}^{1/n}\dfrac{(1-x)^n-1+nx}{x^2}\,dx \le \dfrac{n-1}{2}$$ $$\dfrac{n-1}{e} \le \int_{0}^{1/n}\dfrac{(1-x)^n-1+nx}{x^2}\,dx \le \dfrac{n-1}{2},$$ where we have slightly weakened the lower bound from $n\left(1-\tfrac{1}{n}\right)^n$ to $e^{-1}(n-1)$ in the last step.

For the second piece, we note that $0 \le (1-x)^n \le \left(1-\tfrac{1}{n}\right)^n \le e^{-1}$ for all $x \in [1/n,1]$, and so $$\int_{1/n}^{1}\dfrac{-1+nx}{x^2}\,dx \le \int_{1/n}^{1}\dfrac{(1-x)^n-1+nx}{x^2}\,dx \le \int_{1/n}^{1}\dfrac{e^{-1}-1+nx}{x^2}\,dx$$ $$n\log n - (n-1) \le \int_{1/n}^{1}\dfrac{(1-x)^n-1+nx}{x^2}\,dx \le n\log n - \left(1-\dfrac{1}{e}\right)(n-1)$$

Combining these two bounds yields: $$n\log n - \left(1-\dfrac{1}{e}\right)(n-1) \le \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{(1-x)^n-1+nx}{x^2}\,dx \le n\log n - \left(\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{e}\right)(n-1),$$ and thus, $S_n = n\log n + O(n)$.

Comment: Thank you for this effort. I will quickly read the answer and will ask the doubts if any.

Comment: How did you get $f(0)$=${n}\choose{2}$?

Comment: Admittedly, I glossed over a few details, and was a little sloppy with notation. I should have written $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)$ instead of $f(0)$. Anyway, note that $(1-x)^n = 1-nx+\binom{n}{2}x^2+O(x^3)$ for $x$ near $0$, and so $f(x) = \tfrac{(1-x)^n-1+nx}{x^2} = \binom{n}{2}+O(x)$ for $x$ near $0$. Hence, $\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x) = \binom{n}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. So you proved beautifully that $S_n=n \log n+O(n)$. But what can we say about asymptotic equivalence? Will $S_n \sim n \log n $?

Comment: Yes. If you divide through by $n \log n$, you get $1 - (1-1/e)\tfrac{n-1}{n \log n} \le \tfrac{S_n}{n \log n} \le 1 - (1/2-1/e)\tfrac{n-1}{n \log n}$. Then taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ and applying the squeeze theorem yields $\lim_{n \to \infty}\tfrac{S_n}{n\log n} = 1$, i.e. $S_n \sim n\log n$.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Thank you so much. Thanks really

Comment: Please include this above comment in your answer.